# RXAndroid: Observable wait for another observable complete

Tags: android, reactive-programming, rx-android

I'm using Retrofit and RxAndroid. Now i want to call api to get user information, then use this information as parameter to call another api to get more information.
How should I do to achive this purpose?

P/S: It can be done with callback, but I want to do with RX-Android style

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [flatMap](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/flatmap.html) for this.

Pseudo-code:

```
apiService.getUser()
    .flatMap(user -> apiService.getUserMessages(user.getId()))
    .subscribe(messages -> {

    }, error -> {

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
Observable<User> userObservable = api.getUserInformation();
userObservable.subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new Consumer<User>() {
                    @Override
                    public void accept(User user) throws Exception {
                        //do what you want this the user
                    }
                });
```

The following code would do the operation in a new thread,and would hit the callback on the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

If you want recursion, you should use `concatMap()`. This method will ensure you to have multiple calls in your specified order. `flatMap()` is more random.

You can check for more info on this [link](https://fernandocejas.com/2015/01/11/rxjava-observable-tranformation-concatmap-vs-flatmap/) about this.